# How can I prove this logical statement is a tautology using logical equivalence laws.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I used a truth table and it showed that this is a tautology, although I am unsure how to prove this through logical equivalence laws.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the logical statement.

((p ∨ q) ∧ (p → r) ∧ (¬r)) → q

Comment: What equivalence laws do you have? More importantly, have you made any attempt yourself?

Comment: Yeah I have.  I converted p → r to ¬p ∧ r.